# Compiled TagLib framework for OS X fails at codesign

Tags: xcode, macos, taglib

I created a framework from the v1.9.1 source code of TagLib with the following cmake (targeting Yosemite):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_FRAMEWORK=ON \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++ \
-DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/ \
-DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10 -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64"`
```

I then drag-and-dropped the `tag.framework` file (folder) from /Library/Frameworks/ into my Xcode 7.0 project, ticked the "Copy files if needed" checkbox and checked that the file was indeed present in my project folder. I then added the framework to the "Embedded Binaries", which automatically also adds it to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". I checked that the framework was present in the Build Phases under the "Link binary with libraries" and "Embed frameworks" sections.

I can link to the header files with no error from Xcode (i.e. `#include <tag/mpegfile.h>`) but when I try to compile, I get an error: `Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1`

The compiler gives the following additional info: `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gsytetlenuelapbdgypechfnxbht/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/tag.framework/Versions/A: No such file or directory`

I went and looked in the framework and, indeed, there is no "A" folder in the Versions, but a "1.14.0" folder.. Why is the compiler trying to codesign a version that's not there?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile my xcode project by changing a line in the file `taglib/CMakeLists.txt`, around line 344 (for taglib-1.10beta at least, I decided to use the beta in the mean time) before compiling the framework.
So `VERSION ${TAGLIB_SOVERSION_MAJOR}.${TAGLIB_SOVERSION_MINOR}.${TAGLIB_SOVERSION_PATCH}` becomes `VERSION "A"`.

I have absolutely no idea why Xcode goes looking for a version "A" but there you go..